# User defined function in Entity Framework Core returning null

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, user-defined-functions

I am trying to call an user-defined function with Entity Framework Core. This is the function in SQL Server:

```
create function udf_CreateNextBookingId()
returns varchar(5)
as
begin
    declare @NextBookingId varchar(5)
    
    if not exists (select BookingId from BookingDetails)
        set @NextBookingId = 'B1001'
    else
        select  @NextBookingId = 'B' + cast(cast(SUBSTRING(Max(BookingId),2,4) as int) + 1 as varchar) from BookingDetails

    return @NextBookingId
end
```

I defined this method :

```
public static string CreateNextBookingId()
{
    return null;
}
```

And within the `OnModelCreating` method I used this code:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo").
                HasDbFunction(() => MovieGoDbContext.CreateNextBookingId()).
                HasName("udf_CreateNextBookingId");
```

I am trying to call the function using this code:

```
public string BookTicket()
{
    string nextBookingId = null;

    try
    {
        nextBookingId = contex.BookingDetails
                              .Select(t => MovieGoDbContext.CreateNextBookingId())
                              .FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        nextBookingId = null;
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }

    return nextBookingId;
}
```

But I only got a string with null value. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL generated by EF?

Comment: It may be because you marked the method as static. EF does a lot by inheritance and overriding methods. Marking the method as static would prevent that